# ASP.NET, check for javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I don't understand how does ECMAScript works. Check on MSDN and other forum it didnt tell us which version or values equal to javascrpt.

```
if (!Request.Browser.JavaScript)
 //Do Something.
```

However, I was given a warning of obsolute and recommend me to use ECMAScript instead.

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities myBrowserCaps = Request.Browser;
if (((System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase)myBrowserCaps).EcmaScriptVersion.Major < 1)
//Does not have Javascript. Do something.
```

However, I tried both on/off my javascript. Somehow the function was not fired. I suspect certain values belong to javascript. However, I cant find anything related to value == javascript.

I understand I could a  Then perform a redirect using meta tag. But I would like all these code to perform at the server.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, see [Should I bother to develop for JavaScript disabled?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/should-i-bother-to-develop-for-javascript-disabled) / [How important is graceful degradation of JavaScript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/how-important-is-graceful-degradation-of-javascript) .

Then, client-side Javascript only exists in the client and if it's off, no client-side logic will fire to check anything explicitly. So you cannot know it until the client sends at least one reply from your page (be it a GET/POST query or an XMLHTTPRequest) - i.e. only after the second request from that very user, generated by the very page you sent them, which may never occur if they just lurk around, even if you make every link on your page a form reply - they may use URLs from an external source. A CodeProject article linked from [Check if javascript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422871/check-if-javascript-is-disabled#4422996) is one example of such approach.

For this reason (and to avoid effort duplication to make both script and noscript versions - the practice that saw some use in the past), the best practice appears to have become making pages and frameworks JavaScript-agnostic and just warning the user with `<noscript>` that the page may not be fully functional if it's relevant.

E.g. Sharepoint does just that - with JS disabled, a warning appears on top while on the page, there are e.g. no scrollbars and editing is disabled completely. **Which leads to conclusion that ASP.NET controls (which SP makes heavy use of) weren't designed to be functional beyond basic display with JS disabled in the first place.**